# How detect special characters in string : VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm very new to VueJS, and I'm building an app with a signup and login setup. I want to display to the user if he has enter a special character like `/[&^$*_+~.()\'\"!\-:@]/`. To do that, I used `includes` in my `signup.vue` files. `Includes`works fine with a single word, but not with a series of characters. How can I do that ?

```js
var character = /[&^$*_+~.()\'\"!\-:@]/

if (this.name.includes(character) || this.lastname.includes(character)) {
   this.feedback = 'Special character present, please correct'
}
```

Comment: `character.test(this.name) && character.test(this.lastname)` Also, why are you preventing the `-` character ? Some first names use it (some french examples : Jean-Michel, Marie-Agnès,...). Same for the `'` character (ex: O'Niell)

Comment: I've corrected my var character and I agree it's useless to excluded ```-``` and ```'``` for a form. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

This method works fine

```
var character = /[ `!@#$%^&*()_+\-=[\]{};':"\\|,.<>/?~]/

if (character.test(this.name) || character.test(this.lastname)) {
   this.feedback = 'Special character present, please correct'
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).